# How to specify multiple jdbc drivers in spark context?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an application which reads data from mysql and postgresql and does data processing.

I have the following function which initializes spark :

```
def init_spark():
    global sc, sqlContext, sqlCtx, sql, spark
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config(
         'spark.driver.extraClassPath', 'path/to/mysql-connector-java.jar'
     ).getOrCreate()

    sc = spark.sparkContext
    sql = spark.sql
    atexit.register(lambda: sc.stop())

    # for compatibility
    sqlContext = spark._wrapped
    sqlCtx = sqlContext

    print("""Welcome to
          ____              __
         / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
        _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
       /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version %s
          /_/
    """ % sc.version)
    print("Using Python version %s (%s, %s)" % (
        platform.python_version(),
        platform.python_build()[0],
        platform.python_build()[1]))
    print("SparkSession available as 'spark'.")
```

I have a main file which run the application as below:

```
init_spark()
process_mysql_data()
process_postgresql_data()
```

In this case **process_postgresql_data()** would fail because I have initialized spark with mysql jar. however when I replace it with postgresql jar it does work but I have to comment out **process_mysql_data()** function. I am looking at a more efficient way to achieve this such that it would be automated.

Comment: You can add another .config() parameter with the postgres jar as well: 

```spark = SparkSession.builder \
                     .config( 'spark.driver.extraClassPath', 'path/to/mysql-connector-java.jar)\
                     .config( 'spark.driver.extraClassPath', 'path/to/postgres-connector-java.jar)\
                     .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: It doesnot work since it ovverides the extraclass path.

Answer (score 2):

just put all jars into the same string, separated by `:`, like

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(
 'spark.driver.extraClassPath', 
 'path/to/mysql-connector-java.jar:path/to/postgres-connector-java.jar'
 ).getOrCreate()
```